# How to write test class on Blob method

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, pagereference, blob

I have a PageReference method as given below I am trying to write a test class for this it shows error.

Error Message:

> System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Stack Trace:

> Class.System.EncodingUtil.base64Decode: line 5, column 1
>   Class.TestUnsusbcribe.Unsubscribe: line 12, column 1

how to pass the 'action' value in this Blob method `(Blob decodedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(action);) (line 12)`

please any one give some idea to solve this problem

```
public without sharing class TestUnsusbcribe {  
    public String compid {get;set;}
    public String action {get;set;}     
    public TestUnsusbcribe(){
         compid = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
         action = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('type');         

    }   
    public PageReference Unsubscribe(){    
        Blob decodedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(action);
        String actions = decodedBlob.tostring();       
        if(actions =='emp'){
            Employee__c ageobj = [SELECT Id,Name,Communication_Agreement__c,Email__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Id=:compid];
            if(ageobj !=null){
                ageobj.Communication_Agreement__c = false;
                update ageobj;                
                list<org__c> compobj = [SELECT Id,Name,Communication_Agreement__c,email__c FROM org__c WHERE email__c=:ageobj.Email__c limit 1];

                if(compobj.size()>0 && !compobj.isempty() )
                {
                    compobj[0].Communication_Agreement__c = false;
                    update compobj;
                }                
                pagereference p = apexpages.Currentpage();
                apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'You Successfully opt-out the email communication');
                apexpages.addmessage(msg);
                return p; 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
           @isTest
           Public class Test_TestUnsusbcribe {

           static testMethod void UnsubscribeTest() {

            Test.startTest();

                Employee__c  emply = new Employee__c (First_Name__c='test987',Last_Name__c='test654',Email__c='test9@gmail.com');
                insert emply;

                org__c cmpny= new org__c(Name='test3 User3',email__c='test9@gmail.com',password__c='1234567',Communication_Agreement__c=true);
                Insert cmpny;


                TestUnsusbcribe  Unsusb=new TestUnsusbcribe ();
                String action = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('emp'));
                     Cookie cookie = new Cookie('test9@gmail.com', action, null, 31536000, false);
                    ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{cookie});
                Unsusb.Unsubscribe();

                Test.stopTest();

           }

        }
```

Comment: Post your test class

Comment: @Ankita now added test class also please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `action` and `compId` through `Page Reference` in the test class.

Try this:

```
@isTest
Public class Test_TestUnsusbcribe {

    static testMethod void UnsubscribeTest() {
        Test.startTest();

        Employee__c  emply = new Employee__c (First_Name__c='test987',Last_Name__c='test654',Email__c='test9@gmail.com');
        insert emply;

        org__c cmpny= new org__c(Name='test3 User3',email__c='test9@gmail.com',password__c='1234567',Communication_Agreement__c=true);
        Insert cmpny;

        String action = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('emp'));
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie('test9@gmail.com', action, null, 31536000, false);
        // Pass the page name
        PageReference pageRef = Page.PageName;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('type', action);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id', cmpny.Id);            
        pageRef.setCookies(new Cookie[]{cookie});

        TestUnsusbcribe  Unsusb=new TestUnsusbcribe ();
        Unsusb.Unsubscribe();

        Test.stopTest();

       }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ankita, you are entirely correct. I've updated my testclass for your reference now it's working fine.